# Unable to send metrics to datadog from Datadog agent running as ECS container

Tags: logging, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, datadog

I am running my core business service on ECS Fargate. I have added the 'datadog-agent' as the sidecar container to send metrics of the service running on ECS fargate to datadog.

But, the problem is that I am not getting any metrics on the Datadog itself from the ECS container.

Here are the environment variables I am using for datadog-agent:

- DD_API_KEY
- DD_PROXY_HTTP
- DD_PROXY_HTTPS
- DD_PROXY_NO_PROXY
- DD_SITE
- ECS_FARGATE

I am using these proxy environments variables because I have to pass the metrics through Squid proxy server. I have checked everything possible but still getting the following error:

> 2021-04-30 14:30:33 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/forwarder/worker.go:174
> in process) | Too many errors for endpoint
> 'https://app.datadoghq.us/api/v1/check_run?api_key= {
> "DD_API_KEY": "***************************xxxx" } ': retrying later
>
> 2021-04-30 14:30:29 UTC | CORE | ERROR |
> (pkg/collector/runner/runner.go:292 in work) | Error running check
> consul: [ {
> "message": "400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8500/v1/status/leader",

How can I get metrics successfully on Datadog? I have tried different ways and researched a lot, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The first error message you shared shows that the Agent cannot emit a payload to the Datadog platform.

The second error shown is an error for the ECS Agent to connect to a consul instance to check its status - and is a different problem issue.

Can you provide an example of the value passed in `DD_PROXY_NO_PROXY` ?

From your description, the Datadog Agent is intended to make outbound calls via the Squid proxy - and the proxy configuration may be preventing the outbound calls.

The Proxy configuration details are documented here in further detail:  https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/proxy/?tab=agentv6v7

Comment: Hi @Mike Fiedler . Thank you for your answer.

The value passed on DD_PROXY_NO_PROXY are: 127.0.0.1 localhost *.service.consul 10.0.0.0/8

I did checked the proxy configuration details as well. I have used the environment variables instead of datadog.yml file for the configuration regarding the proxy. 

I am checked the outbound security groups. The service is allowed outbound to proxy server and the proxy server allows outbound to datadoghq.